# Loading Error caused while doing snapshot.connectionState (in Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to make word quiz program, and while I try to code quiz program, there are some errors in this code, especially about snapshot.connectionState.
I used firestore and flutter and dart language.
In my cord there is endless CircularProgressIndicator(), meaning snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting.

I already checked internet network (no problem).

Belows are my quiz page code. Please help me anyone.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChooseQuiz extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChooseQuiz({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChooseQuiz> createState() => _ChooseQuizState();
}


class _ChooseQuizState extends State<ChooseQuiz> {
  late int randomIndex;
  List<String> correctAnswers = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [];
  late List<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> quizList = [];
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? snapshot;
  List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> quizDocuments = [];
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> stream;

  Future<List<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>> getSnapshots() async {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = await firestore.collection('WORDS').get();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(snapshot.docs.length);
      var quiz = firestore.collection('WORDS').orderBy('id').startAfter([snapshot.docs[randomIndex]]).snapshots();
      quizList.add(quiz);
    }

    return Future.value(quizList);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSnapshots();
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getRandomDocuments(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot) async {
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> documents = querySnapshot.docs;

    data.clear(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document = documents[i];
      if (!correctAnswers.contains(document.id)) {
        print('Added ${document.id} to correctAnswers list');
        correctAnswers.add(document.id);
        print('${correctAnswers}');
        data.add(document.data()!);
      }
    }

    if (data.length < 4) {
      return getRandomDocuments(querySnapshot);
    }
    randomIndex = Random().nextInt(4);
    return data;
  }

  Future<void> updateSnapshot() async {
    if (quizDocuments.isNotEmpty) {
      quizDocuments.clear();
      FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> stream = await firestore.collection('WORDS').orderBy('eng').limit(4).snapshots();

    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < quizList.length; i++)
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
            stream: quizList[0],
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                return Center(child: Text('An error occurred'));
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                final KOR = snapshot.data!.docs[0]['kor'] as String;
                final ENG = snapshot.data!.docs[0]['eng'] as String;
                int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(4);
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(KOR),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                if (snapshot.data!.docs[(randomIndex + j) % 4]['eng'] == ENG) {
                                  await showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return AlertDialog(
                                        content: Text('맞았어요!'),
                                        actions: [
                                          TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () async {
                                              Navigator.pop(context);
                                              await updateSnapshot();
                                            },
                                            child: Text('확인'),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  await showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return AlertDialog(
                                        content: Text('틀렸어요! 답은${ENG}'),
                                        actions: [
                                          TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () async {
                                              Navigator.pop(context);
                                              updateSnapshot();
                                            },
                                            child: Text('확인'),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text(snapshot.data!.docs[(randomIndex + j) % 4]['eng']),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('퀴즈다시시작!'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
              }
            },
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Firstly, I tried to implement quiz program using Future. At that time it worked, but because I couldn't change one quiz to another quiz, I changed my mind to use Stream method.

And I think there's some error while using Stream in my code. 

Please help me anyone and teach me how to solve this problem.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you perform any troubleshooting by stepping through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected? If you did, please include your findings - what line isn't working? Where does the code start to fail? Please update the question.